# Segmentation Fault While Encrypting with Openssl EVP: EVP_EncryptUpdate()

Tags: c, openssl, segmentation-fault

I want to use EVP and OpenSSL API to encrypt the binary data from a .exe file that I read into an unsigned char *. I'm not super familiar with this API and I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong that is causing the segmentation fault that I get when I compile. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

void handleErrors(void){
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  abort();
}

int main(){
  //read in the exe file and convert its bytes to a string
  FILE *inFile;
  inFile = fopen("Quasar.exe","rb");
  if (inFile == NULL){
    perror("Failed to read in file\n");
  }

  printf("File read in complete!\n");

  if(fseek(inFile , 0 , SEEK_END) == -1){
    perror("Offset error\n");
  };
    unsigned long lSize = ftell(inFile);
  if (lSize == -1){
    perror("Size error\n");
  }
    rewind(inFile);

  unsigned char *unencryptedText = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char)*lSize);
    fread(unencryptedText,1,lSize,inFile);
    fclose(inFile);

  unsigned char *encryptedText = (unsigned char*) malloc (3 *(sizeof(unsigned char)*lSize));

  //encrypt these bytes with open ssl
  printf("Encrypting...\n");
  int outlen, tmplen;
  unsigned char key[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
  unsigned char iv[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = NULL;

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
  EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_idea_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);

  if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, encryptedText, &outlen, unencryptedText, lSize)){
    return 0;
  }
      
  if(!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, encryptedText + outlen, &tmplen)){
    return 0;
  }
  outlen += tmplen;
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the console output:

```
File read in complete!
Encrypting...
zsh: segmentation fault  ./binary
```

Here is the Make script:

```
all: crypter.c 
    gcc -Wall -g -I/usr/local/include/openssl -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto crypter.c -o binary
clean: 
    rm -f crypter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = NULL;

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_idea_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
```

At no time do you assign `ctx` any value other than `NULL`. You pass a `NULL` to both of the functions above.

What you probably wanted was:

```
ECP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
```

Notice how this doesn't pass `NULL` to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init`?

Comment: If I change ECP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = NULL; to EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx. I start getting the error: `crypter.c:44:18: error: variable has incomplete type 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX' (aka
      'struct evp_cipher_ctx_st')
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/types.h:102:16: note: forward declaration of
      'struct evp_cipher_ctx_st'
typedef struct evp_cipher_ctx_st EVP_CIPHER_CTX;`

Comment: Then you want `EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();`.

Comment: That fixed it thank you! For some reason, my EVP_EncryptUpdate() function is returning failure, any idea why that would be?

Comment: Add code to dump OpenSSL's error log using [these functions](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/ERR_get_error.html).

Comment: Here is what im getting: `008EE00901000000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:332:Global default library context, Algorithm (IDEA-CBC : 6), Properties ()
008EE00901000000:error:03000083:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptUpdate:no cipher set:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:610:` Sorry I'm a bit new and lost at what this means!

Comment: @James It sounds like your version of OpenSSL doesn't provide support for IDEA or, by default, doesn't enable it. Is there some particular reason you're trying to use an algorithm that has been obsolete for a decade? (Significant weaknesses in IDEA were discovered in 2002.)

Comment: I didn't know it was obsolete haha, I was trying to use AES, hopefully there's an aes option

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a NULL object to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init`  This function expects the address of an existing `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` object.

You can fix this by creating an instance of `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` and passing its address to each function that needs it, or if you want to minimize changes to your code you can assign the address of this object to the existing `ctx` pointer.

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx_obj;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = &ctx_obj;
```

EDIT:

Based on the comments, it seems you're using OpenSSL 1.1 or later.  In that case, you want to instead use `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new` to instantiate a new context:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
```

Comment: If I change ECP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = NULL; to EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx. I start getting the error: `crypter.c:44:18: error: variable has incomplete type 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX' (aka
      'struct evp_cipher_ctx_st')
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/openssl/types.h:102:16: note: forward declaration of
      'struct evp_cipher_ctx_st'
typedef struct evp_cipher_ctx_st EVP_CIPHER_CTX;`

Comment: @James See my edit.  Use `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new`.